# Who are the most popular Selenium Automation experts and advocates?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, people, test-engineering

I am a newbie in Selenium WebDriver and have started my journey of learning the tools. I wanted to follow blogs/articles/tutorials of most famous and expert Automation engineers who work primarily on Selenium based frameworks.

Can you provide a reference list of Automation experts whose material I can read and benefit from.

Thanks!!

Comment: Voting for close due to Opionion-Based. Please, read the How to Ask guide for understanding the scope of Stack Exchange questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask